# Relative top position of an overflow scrolling list in IE8/9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, scroll, position

I have an interaction where I have an `<ul>` with a long list of `<li>`s wrapped inside a `<div>` container to make them scrollable.

Now I transition the list to a state where I want to show a specific `<li>`as the top item. I can't do this by using the `scrollTop` property since the item may be to far to the bottom to be able to scroll it in the desired position at the top of the container.

That's why I set the relative top position of the ul to the desired value.

Please have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pJfNp/13/

In all browsers except IE8 & 9 the active/red item is shown at the top, but Internet Explorer seems to not be able to "detach" the bottom of the `<ul>` from the `<div>`, it somehow stays anchored there. Just what would happen if I had tried to use `scrollTop` to show it as the first item.

I'm open to new ideas on how to do something similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested in IE8, should work in IE9 too :)

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pJfNp/14/)*

```
var liHeight = $('li.active').height();
$('ul').height( $('ul').height() + (liHeight*3) );
var activePos = $('li.active').position().top;
$('div').animate({scrollTop:activePos},1000);
```

if you need to display sometimes the last `li` that means that you need extra 3 `li heights` so just multiply it with 3 and add the result to the the `ul` element height.

Than to animate, animate the `scrollTop` of your `div`

Comment: Thanks, increasing the height of the `<ul>` works and got me thinking. I've now come up with a solution which scrolls to the top of the area as the top positon value is animated in parallel: http://jsfiddle.net/pJfNp/18/

Comment: @samy-delux Glad you did it - Well... if you like the answer... ;)

Comment: Accepted your answer, as it gave me a good idea on how to fix my specific problem.